# Buscas em Objetos sem saber o nome do atributo

Tags: javascript, json

Tenho um objeto bastante extenso na qual preciso fazer uma busca nele. Tenho vários objetos dentro e vários arrays.Por esse motivo não seria viável ir dando um `console.log` em cada atributo até encontrar o que queria. Seria um tanto quanto trabalhoso,portanto,queria saber se há uma forma de fazer uma pesquisa dentro de um objeto a partir de uma string, seria algo como:
***DentroDeObjeto objeto busque por "string"*** o código que criei foi esse aqui

```js
var xml         = require("fs");
var parser      = require('fast-xml-parser');
var wtf         = require('wtf_wikipedia');


xml.readFile('wiktionary.part_9.xml',function(erro,documento){  

     if(erro){
        console.log("ERRO: " + erro);
     }

    var tObj = parser.getTraversalObj(documento);
    var jsonObj = parser.convertToJson(tObj);
    var t  = wtf(jsonObj.mediawiki.page.revision.text).json();

});
```

Porém não sei como fazer para consultar dentro do objeto T que me retorna

```js
{ title: undefined,
  categories:
   [ 'Substantivo (Português)',
     'Substantivo (Esperanto)',
     'Cognato (Esperanto)',
     'Substantivo (Franco-Provençal)',
     'Substantivo (Galego)',
     'Substantivo (Ido)' ],
  sections:
   [ { title: '', depth: 0, paragraphs: [Array], templates: [Array] },
     { title: 'Substantivo',
       depth: 0,
       paragraphs: [Array],
       templates: [Array],
       lists: [Array] },
     { title: 'Expressões',
       depth: 1,
       paragraphs: [Array],
       lists: [Array] },
     { title: '', depth: 1, paragraphs: [Array], templates: [Array] },
     { title: 'Tradução',
       depth: 1,
       paragraphs: [Array],
       templates: [Array] },
     { title: '', depth: 0, templates: [Array] },
     { title: 'Ver também', depth: 0 },
     { title: 'No Wikcionário',
       depth: 1,
       paragraphs: [Array],
       templates: [Array],
       lists: [Array] },
     { title: 'Expressões',
       depth: 2,
       paragraphs: [Array],
       templates: [Array],
       lists: [Array] },
     { title: 'Apêndices', depth: 2, paragraphs: [Array] },
     { title: 'Wikisaurus',
       depth: 2,
       paragraphs: [Array],
       templates: [Array] },
     { title: 'Substantivo',
       depth: 0,
       paragraphs: [Array],
       templates: [Array] },
     { title: '', depth: 0, templates: [Array] },
     { title: '', depth: 0, paragraphs: [Array], templates: [Array] },
     { title: 'Ver também', depth: 0 },
     { title: 'No Wikcionário',
       depth: 1,
       paragraphs: [Array],
       templates: [Array] },
     { title: 'Substantivo',
       depth: 0,
       paragraphs: [Array],
       templates: [Array] },
     { title: 'Ver também', depth: 0 },
     { title: 'No Wikcionário',
       depth: 1,
       paragraphs: [Array],
       templates: [Array] },
     { title: 'Substantivo',
       depth: 0,
       paragraphs: [Array],
       templates: [Array] },
     { title: 'Ver também', depth: 0 },
     { title: 'No Wikcionário',
       depth: 1,
       paragraphs: [Array],
       templates: [Array] },
     { title: 'Substantivo',
       depth: 0,
       paragraphs: [Array],
       templates: [Array] },
     { title: 'Ver também', depth: 0 },
     { title: 'No Wikcionário', depth: 1, templates: [Array] } ] }
```

Como vocês podem ver,são varios objetos e arrays e não sei onde está o que procuro,seria bem trabalhoso ir varrendo todo o objeto

Comment: Procure sempre colocar o seu código e onde você está com dificuldades, o que você já tentou fazer... mais fácil conseguir ajuda assim aqui no fórum

Comment: Obrigado,criei a conta hoje,não sei direito como usar o fórum

Comment: De uma olhada na central de ajuda do fórum, vai ajudar nas próximas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você precisa é de uma function recursiva, que busque pelos diversos níveis do objeto. Mais ou menos assim:

```
function findStringInObj(obj, string) {
    for (let i in obj) {
        if (obj[i] instanceof Object) { // Se o elemento for um objeto, procure dentro dele tbm
            findStringInObj(obj[i], string);
        } else if (typeof obj[i] === "string") { // Se for uma string vamos verificar o valor
            if (obj[i].indexOf(string) > -1) {
                console.log(obj[i]);  // Encontrou a string. O que fazer com ela agora?
            }
        }
    }
}

findStringInObj(obj, "Expressões");
```

Comment: Ele não mostra nada, em console.log(obj[i]); não seria pra mostrar o que encontrou?

Comment: @mecatrônicacomreciclagem Se não está mostrando nada é porque não encontro a string que vc está buscando. Tem certeza que ela existe no objeto?

Comment: Desculpe,é verdade,resolveu aqui,obrigado